How to get user regional settings in a browser? Not user language
My Windows11 language is english but my regional settings is set to danish.
When I run the below code 'en-GB' is returned. I expected 'da-DK' to be returned.
    function getUserLocale() {
        const intl = window.Intl;
        if (intl !== undefined) {
            return intl.NumberFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;
        }

        // Old standard.
        return navigator.language ?? "en-US";
    }


Some documentation - does it conflict with your findings? - PS: hav en god dag ;)

Yep. Still returns 'en-GB' going directly on the Intl object. Bummer.

It seems that chrome is returning the selected language in its settings rather than the Regional Settings of the OS. This sux!
I like my os and browser running english but need regional settings to be danish.

@Holm76 Can't you set the browser content language independently from the UI language?

It does not seem so. At least not on the Chrome installed on my machine. The language selected was the locale value returned from the above function.
